# How to remove elements from a multiset of structs in c++?

Tags: c++, multiset

Here is what I tried to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int x;
    int y;
};
multiset<node> mset;
int main() {
    node b=node();
    b={1,2};
    mset.insert({1,2});
    mset.erase(b);
    cout<<mset.size()<<endl;
    cout<<b.y;
    return 0;
}
```

it doesn't seem to work. It gives the following  compilation error and I couldn't understand it.

[ideone link](https://ideone.com/WKf0n7)

I have gone through a thread regarding removing elements from a multiset of structs but it didn't seem to help either.

EDIT:
since people are complaining here is the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = node]’:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1867:51:   required from ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_get_insert_equal_pos(const key_type&) [with _Key = node; _Val = node; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<node>; _Compare = std::less<node>; _Alloc = std::allocator<node>; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = node]’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1916:27:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_equal(_Arg&&) [with _Arg = node; _Key = node; _Val = node; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<node>; _Compare = std::less<node>; _Alloc = std::allocator<node>; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<node>]’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_multiset.h:479:51:   required from ‘std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Key = node; _Compare = std::less<node>; _Alloc = std::allocator<node>; std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<node>; std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = node]’
prog.cpp:13:19:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const node’ and ‘const node’)
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:437:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator<(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:437:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:298:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator<(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:298:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:355:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator<(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:355:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1137:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator<(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1137:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1143:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)
     operator<(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1143:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5150:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5150:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5163:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
     operator<(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5163:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5175:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5175:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘node’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:46:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/system_error:200:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator<(const std::error_code&, const std::error_code&)
   operator<(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/system_error:200:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const node’ to ‘const std::error_code&’
/usr/include/c++/6/system_error:274:3: note: candidate: bool std::operator<(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_condition&)
   operator<(const error_condition& __lhs,
   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/system_error:274:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const node’ to ‘const std::error_condition&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/set:60:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1292:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1292:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/set:61:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_set.h:857:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_set.h:857:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/set:62:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_multiset.h:840:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_multiset.h:840:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const node’ is not derived from ‘const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
```

EDIT:
It worked I just had to add a boolean operator< to compare two nodes.

The ideone link has been edited.

Comment: why don't you paste the compilation error in the question body?

Comment: it's too big. would be inconvenient to read.

Comment: also, try `mset.erase(b)` instead of `mset.erase(node b)`

Comment: Try removing `node` in the erase call

Comment: is it convenient to have to click on a link to get crucial information?

Comment: Your node doesn't have a "<" operator, so it can't be used with `std::multiset`. Either define that or specify template parameter `Compare`  of `std::multiset` to define a comparator. Other possible solution: replace `node` with `std::pair<int,int>` which already has "<" operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error says that there is no `bool operator<(node, node)`. Implement one. E.g.:

```
#include <tuple>

inline bool operator<(node const& a, node const& b) { 
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a comparator which is required for associative containers. Add

```
bool operator<(const node& a, const node& b)
{
  return a.x < b.x ? true : (a.x == b.x ? a.y < b.y : false);
}
```

Comment: That returns `true` for `{2,1} < {1,2}`.

Comment: The correct implementation would be `return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);`. But if you add more member variables this code is going to be more complex. Just use `std::tie`.